# How do I ensure that my AutoConfiguration class depends on Flyway migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Currently some of my AutoConfiguration classes are failing because flyway migration hasn't been executed. How do I ensure that the migration is done before my configuration class is autoconfigured.

I have tried using the `@DependsOn("flyway")` and also `@ConditionalOnBean(Flyway.class)` but neither of them is working so far.

I don't want to write my own migration, I know one is created by defualt because I can autowire the Flyway bean and everything works fine. Autowiring the Flyway bean is pointless because I do not use it.

Comment: Are you looking for `@AutoConfigureAfter`?

Comment: @chrylis After what? I've tried FlywayAutoConfiguration and it doesn't work.